# Ruby on Rails error when using same form on multiple pages

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, contact-form

I have a contact form setup and working on my 'Contact' page. However, when I copy that form to another page I get this error: 'First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty'.

Here is my contactcontroller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])

    if @contact.valid?
      ContactMailer.contact_email(@contact).deliver_now
      redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Your email has been sent. Thank you."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

Here is the other page controller:

```
class GolfcoursesController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery

  def index
    @golf_courses = GolfCourse.all
  end

  def show
    @golf_courses = GolfCourse.all
    @golfcourse = GolfCourse.find_by(slug: params[:slug])
    @holes = @golfcourse.golf_holes
  end

  def events
  end

  def membership
  end

  def practice_facilities
  end

  def contact
  end

  def golf
    @golf_courses = GolfCourse.all
  end

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])

    if @contact.valid?
      ContactMailer.contact_email(@contact).deliver_now
      redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Your email has been sent. Thank you."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the form:

```
<div class="container">
    <h4>Let us know if you have any questions.</h4>
    <%= form_for @contact, :html => {:role => 'form'} do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :name, 'Enter your name:' %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :email, 'Email:' %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :message, 'Message:' %>
          <%= f.text_area :message, class: 'form-control', :rows => 3 %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
        </div>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by "another page"? Does the "other page" have a non-`nil` `Contact` instance? If it's being shown by another controller action the `ContactController` has nothing do do with it.

Comment: It's not being shown in another controller. Basically, all I did was copy and paste the contact form from the contact page onto another page that needs a contact form as well. I didn't change anything else in any other files.

Comment: Which controller action is your new page?

Comment: @eirikir, I added the controller for the second page to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty'

You should also initialize the `@contact` in your other controller.

If you would like to share forms, I'd suggest the use of partials and passing in locals. This makes your code also somewhat DRY.

For reference also see the rails guides: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Bryan. I added the @contact to the other page controller with no change in error. As far as using partials is concerned - there are some variations in the forms. I am completely new to Rails. So I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face. I just don't realize it...

Comment: So which action are you calling in your other controller to show the page? The action 'contact' by any chance?  If so, then you haven't define the `@contact` in that action yet. Or are you calling a different action?

Comment: I finally got it. You were right. I wasn't understanding you right. In the 'other page controller' I called @contact in the wrong place. Thanks sooo much for your help, Bryan!!!